# Get the array key with the highest value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array like

```
arr[1] = 234;
arr[2] = 345;
...

arr[40] = 126;
```

How can I get the index of the element with the highest value without reiterating the array?

Comment: There is no built in operation that will do this. You'll have to write your own function using a loop.

Answer (score 19):

You can apply Math.max and pass the array as its arguments-

```
arr.indexOf(Math.max.apply(window,arr))
```

But now Math.max is doing the iterating, just as sort would do.

**Somebody** has to look at each item in an unsorted array...

Answer (score 10):

With jQuery, is as simple as:

```
// Get the max value from the array    
maxValue = Math.max.apply(this, arr);

// Get the index of the max value, through the built in function inArray
$.inArray(maxValue,arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

If the array is not ordered you cannot do this without iterating.

Answer (score 3):

Get the array key with the highest value in javascript

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var max_car_result = cars[cars.length-1];
alert(max_car_result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var max_index = -1;
var max_value = Number.MIN_VALUE;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] > max_value)
    {
        max_value = arr[i];
        max_index = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function to set the variable.  And keep track of the max in that function.  Here's a quick example without type checking, testing, or support for removing a value.

```
Array.prototype.maxValue = null;

Array.prototype.setIndex = function(index, value){
  this[index] = value;
  if (value > this.maxValue || this.maxValue == null)
    this.maxValue = value;
}


var arr = new Array();
arr.setIndex(0, 234);
arr.setIndex(1, 500);
arr.setIndex(2, -5);

var maxValue = arr.maxValue;
```

Obviously this is nicer if you're currently setting items like this:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 500;
arr[2] = 2;
```

Rather than this:

```
var arr = { 1, 500, 2 };
```

The downside is its not natural and requires you to use function to get the correct results.

Comment: Nice and non-cpu-intensive solution!

Answer (score 1):

Keep the array sorted or use a heap.

Otherwise iterate.  Even if you found some trick to do it it would still require iterating underneath so why not iterate?

If it seems like too much code, put it in a separate routine.

Answer (score 0):

Two solution: to sort descending order and get the first element or:

```
function bigger(array) {
  if (array.length < 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  bigger = 0;
  for(var i=1; i<array.length;i++ ) { 
    if(array[i] > array[bigger]) {
      bigger = i;
    }
  }
  return bigger;
}
```

you cold optimize using two variables, one for the position and other for the content.

Answer (score 0):

Either you will have iteration somewhere (in your code or in JQuery.each()) or you can define something like this:

```
Array.prototype.mpush = function(v)
{
  var maxv = this.maxValue || Number.MIN_VALUE;
  if( v > maxv ) { this.maxValue = v; this.maxIndex = this.length; }
  this.push(v);
}
```

and use that `arr.mpush(v)` to populate your array. In this case the array will have maxIndex property.

Answer (score 0):

Is old question but here is an my simple emulation of PHP script `max()` made in javascript:

```
function max(array){
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call( array ) === '[object Array]'){
        return array[(array.length-1)];
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

This return value of last key in array or `0` if nothing found.

Maby someone helps.

You can use it like:

```
var array = ['bananaman','spiderman','ironman','superman','batman','manman'];
var getLast = max(array);
if(getLast !== 0)
    alert(getLast); // manman
```