# Javascript max value of array and find where it is?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, max

javascript question here...

I need to find the highest number in an array and then return where in the array this number is. It cannot be sorted as this needs to match up with a word in another array. Heres the array:

```
var array1 = dan, john, james, harry, mike;
var array2 = 66, 33, 85, 34, 45;
```

Basically the number must match up with the name its already with. If anyone has the answer I would be most happy :)

Thanks

Comment: Are these numbers unique?

Comment: ...if not just implement your own "for" cycle where you search for the maximum (and you store its index too).

Comment: Take a look here, I think this will resolve your problem =)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850956/get-the-array-key-with-the-highest-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is search script:

```
var array1 = ['dan', 'john', 'james', 'harry', 'mike'];
var array2 = [66, 33, 85, 34, 45];
var max = array2.length-1;
for (var i=array2.length-1; i--;) {
   if (array2[i] > array[max]) {
      max = i;
   }
}
alert(array1[max]);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var array1    = [ 'dan', 'john', 'james', 'harry', 'mike' ],
    array2    = [ 66, 33, 85, 34, 45 ],
    maxPos    = Math.max.apply( null, array2 ),
    posInArr  = array2.indexOf( maxPos );

console.log( array1[ posInArr ] );  // 'james'
```

The above code demonstrates the usage of `Math.max()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()` to get the highest number within `array2` and then find the index of that number in that array.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var array1 = dan, john, james, harry, mike;


  Array.max = function( array ){
        return array1.indexOf(Math.max.apply( Math, array ));
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read your array into a loop. If the number read is higher than the previous one, store it into a variable, with a second variable for its index.

At the end you'll have the max of your array and its index.